# Application doesn't work properly if I remove a printf

Tags: java, c, contiki

I have a Contiki application which is driving me crazy.

I have to compute the energetic consumption of the Tmote Sky. I'm using energest, and this is the piece of code that I use in the energy consumption estimation function, which is periodically called:

```
lpm_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_LPM);
cpu_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_CPU);
rx_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_LISTEN);
tx_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT);
lpm = lpm_time - prev_times.lpm_time;
cpu = cpu_time - prev_times.cpu_time;
rx = rx_time - prev_times.rx_time;
tx = tx_time - prev_times.tx_time;

consumed_energy = (I_LPM * lpm + I_CPU * cpu + I_RX * rx + I_TX * tx) * VOLTS / RTIMER_ARCH_SECOND;  /* mJ = mA * seconds * volts */

/*printf("lpm %lu, cpu %lu, rx %lu, tx %lu, prl %lu, prc %lu, prr %lu, prt %lu\n",
       lpm_time, cpu_time, rx_time, tx_time, prev_times.lpm_time, prev_times.cpu_time, prev_times.rx_time, prev_times.tx_time);*/

prev_times.lpm_time = lpm_time;
prev_times.cpu_time = cpu_time;
prev_times.rx_time = rx_time;
prev_times.tx_time = tx_time;
```

The problem is that the application works properly only if the `printf` that now is commented is enabled.
If it stays commented as it is, I can either receive meaningless values for the `consumed_energy` variable, or the COOJA simulation stops with a Java `Illegal read - out of bounds` message.

Why does this happen??? What can be the reason?
It is a very strange thing.

Thanks in advance.

---

The full code of this file is this:

```
volatile static struct energest_times prev_times;


float update_consumption()
{
    uint32_t lpm_time;
    uint32_t cpu_time;
    uint32_t rx_time;
    uint32_t tx_time;
    uint32_t lpm;
    uint32_t cpu;
    uint32_t rx;
    uint32_t tx;
    float consumed_energy;

    lpm_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_LPM);
    cpu_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_CPU);
    rx_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_LISTEN);
    tx_time = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT);
    lpm = lpm_time - prev_times.lpm_time;
    cpu = cpu_time - prev_times.cpu_time;
    rx = rx_time - prev_times.rx_time;
    tx = tx_time - prev_times.tx_time;

    consumed_energy = (I_LPM * lpm + I_CPU * cpu + I_RX * rx + I_TX * tx) * VOLTS / RTIMER_ARCH_SECOND;  /* mJ = mA * seconds * volts */

    printf("lpm %lu, cpu %lu, rx %lu, tx %lu, prl %lu, prc %lu, prr %lu, prt %lu\n",
            lpm_time, cpu_time, rx_time, tx_time, prev_times.lpm_time, prev_times.cpu_time, prev_times.rx_time, prev_times.tx_time);

    prev_times.lpm_time = lpm_time;
    prev_times.cpu_time = cpu_time;
    prev_times.rx_time = rx_time;
    prev_times.tx_time = tx_time;

    printf("Consumed energy: %ld\n", (int32_t) consumed_energy);

    return consumed_energy;
}
```

The function is periodically called by another function, once every minute.

Comment: Well is it java or C??

Comment: @z̍̄̒ͪ̚  I don't think Java has `printf()`.

Comment: @aliants Show more code, this fragment is very small. The symptoms point towards memory corruption.

Comment: @RobinHellemans Sure, but the code is obviously not using `System.out`.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. So if printf() does not give any compiler errors this is probably C code

Comment: Sorry, I had problems with the internet connectivity in the last 3 hours. :( In the meantime I solved the problem: it seems to be a compiler optimization problem. I declared the struct `prev_times` as `volatile static` and now it works well also without the `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this in Java, or C if you have multiple threads using a library which is not thread safe.  In this situation, you some times get the right value and sometimes you get half right and sometimes you get non-sense.

If you add a printf e.g. System.out.printf() or any IO or sleep() or step through the code using debugging, this really slows down your application so each thread spends a very small percentage of it's time in the library and thus indirectly avoids conflicts.

Are you using multiple threads?  Is the library/methods you are calling thread safe?

Comment: I suppose we can reasonably assume there is a race condition somewhere. If the `volatile` keyword, as used in the declaration of `prev_times`, has a meaning anywhere close to that of Java, I would say that the printf actually changes the value of `prev_times` that is visible by the current thread.

Comment: @Lolo `volatile` in C means it cannot be optimised away.  It doesn't imply visibiliy/threads afety.